# Dropping non-commutative product in the end

Tags: code-request, sorting, products

Suppose my expressions are given as a combinations of non-commutative products, i.e., $2 X**Y**Z + 3 Y**Z**X$, I want to make this as commutative product and get $5 X**Y**Z$. And want similar things for higher length operations, i.e., $X**Y**Z**W**K$.

I have a long list of inputs with $X**Y**Z**\cdots$  and my first trial was just replacing $X**Y \mapsto X*Y$ or $Y**X \mapsto X**Y$ but i realized it did not worked well and i need a lots of expressions for practical use.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. For a non commutative multiply x**y  is not equal to y**x. If you want to set them equal you may simply replace non-commutative-multiply by the ordinary multiply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply replace `NonCommutativeMultiply` by `Times` as follows:

```
2X**Y**Z+3Y**Z**X/.NonCommutativeMultiply->Times
(* 5X Y Z *)
```

Alternatively, you can use your approach with patterns:

```
2X**Y**Z+3Y**Z**X//.x_**y_:> x y
(* 5X Y Z *)
```

(Note the use of `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) to repeatedly apply the replacement until the result doesn't change anymore)

Finally, you could use `BlankSequence` (`__`) in the pattern to replace arbitrarily long products in one step:

```
2X**Y**Z+3Y**Z**X/.x_**y__:> x y
(* 5X Y Z *)
```